# Why would using strchr before using strtok speed up runtime?

Tags: c, performance, optimization

I have this code:

```
void
fill_array (unsigned int *iarray, char *string, int max)
{
  int ipos = 0;
  char *iholder;

  iholder = strtok (string, ",");
  while (iholder != NULL)
    {
      iarray[ipos++] = atoi (iholder);
      if (ipos == max)
    {
      return;
    }
      iholder = strtok (NULL, ",");
    }

}
```

It takes a string "1,2,3,4" for example, and enters the numbers into an array.
I put this in a loop and got 3.3 seconds runtime.

With this code:

```
void
fill_array (unsigned int *iarray, char *string, int max)
{
  int ipos = 0;
  char *iholder;
  if (!strchr (string, ','))
    {
      iarray[0] = atoi (string);
      return;
    }
  iholder = strtok (string, ",");
  while (iholder != NULL)
    {
      iarray[ipos++] = atoi (iholder);
      if (ipos == max)
    {
      return;
    }
      iholder = strtok (NULL, ",");
    }

}
```

It took about 1.4 seconds to execute.

The only difference is the strchr which I inserted just to see if it would run faster on single numbers, but it runs much faster on longer lists for some reason.

Can anyone explain why?

I am testing with this code:

```
int main ()
{
  unsigned int iarray[5];
  char str_test[] = "56,75,22,83";
  int i;
  struct timeval start;
  struct timeval end;

  gettimeofday (&start, NULL);


  for (i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
      fill_array (iarray, str_test, 5);
    }

  gettimeofday (&end, NULL);
  if (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec < 0)
    {
      end.tv_usec += 1000000L;
      end.tv_sec -= 1;
    }

  printf ("Runtime: %ld s %03ld ms\n",
      end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec, (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1000);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably that first strchr is making your code drop out earlier so that it doesn't have to do as much processing?

Comment: Thats what I thought, but I printed out the array, and its filled with all the numbers in the list.

Comment: seems not correct as if "1,2,3,4" is passed, it will never come in `strchr` check. and theoretically it should take more time as processing one extra function call.

Comment: I am stupid, and missed the obvious. strtok modifies the string that it is passed. After the first pass, it does drop out after that strchr.

Answer (score 2):

Seems strange? Are you testing both codes on same machine? and how many times do you have taken the sample? and what is the code you are using to calculate time? please share that as well.

Comment: I tested it on Windows with Dev-c++ and a Debian machine, both yielded  quicker runtimes by adding the strchr.

Comment: Are you using profiler for time measurement or you have written some code for that? if so, please share it.

Comment: @ZPS, remember that `strtok` does modify the contents of string you are passing, and as you are passing one string again and again, so I think that after first execution the string passed will not contain the actual value "56,75,22,83" in that. Test one thing, print the contents of `string` parameter also, and loop less time for debug say 2 times.

Comment: Yeah your right Ummar, I copied the passed string into a temporary variable and ran the tests again. They turned out as expected